# .NET MAUI msbuild fails when there is a library dependency

Tags: msbuild, maui, maui-blazor, maui-windows

If i run the regular MSbuild  `msbuild /restore SmartcardMAUITest.csproj /restore /t:Publish /p:TargetFramework=net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 /p:configuration=release` (I have to use msbuild instead of dotnet publish due to legacy references).  it works however if I add an empty .net 7 library reference the build breaks with the following error

> error NETSDK1005: Assets file '\Smartca
> rdMAUITest\ClassLibrary1\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net7.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net7.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [\SmartcardMAUITest\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj]

is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error `NETSDK1005`, You can read this document about [NETSDK1005 and NETSDK1047: Asset file is missing target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1005) to fix this error.

You need to make sure that the missing target value is included in the TargetFrameworks property of your project. Opening the .csproj file and check the targetframework.

Here is the [related issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8304) on the GitHub, you can follow up it and get more information.